# my iPhone app skips the splash screen!

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPhone app. When I have installed it in the device, it worked fine, ie it showed, the logo screen, the title screen and goes to game screen and now I have exited pressing the home button. The problems starts when I relaunch the app, it straightly goes to the game screen, by skipping the splash screens.

While I was working on it the app crashed and when I launched again it showed the logo screen and title screen. But when I relaunched it, the splash screens where skipped.

Could you tell me the possible errors that might have occurred?

Answer (score 5):

It's not an error, it's iOS4 multitasking.

Your app keeps running in the background as long as there are resources available.

Comment: So what should I do if I want to display right from splash screen?

Comment: It's a setting in Info.plist in the XCode project for the application.   

It's called UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend. If you set it to YES the application will exit when it gets suspended.   

Here's a link to the Information Property List Key Reference that talks about it.  
 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: As a user, I would very much like to be able to pop out for a quick SMS and get right back into the game. Enabling this setting will seriously annoy me.